# gcache.page_sizes and gcache.size are set at the same time. When will gcache.pagebe used?

Tags: galera

After the power failure and restart, the slave node creates a large number of gcache.page, which occupies the disk.

I would like to know if there is already gcache.cache, when will gcache.page be created?

```
gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; 
gcache.mem_size = 0; 
gcache.page_size = 128M; 
gcache.size = 128M;
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do and what you are wondering about. Could you clarify what is your issue, and what files you are getting (a listing of the problematic datadir).

Answer (score 2):

The gcache is a ringbuffer and the size of it is set with `gcache.size` and write-sets are appended to this file and the file can be reused.

If the transaction write-set is large enough not to fit in the the gcache ringbuffer then an physical disk file, a page, is allocated to cache the write-sets. Note that there are two types of pages:

1. A page with a standard size as defined by `gcache.page_size` (default=128M as above).
2. A page with non-standard page size is created if the transaction is large enough not to fit into a standard page. With a `gcache.page_size` of 1M and transaction write-set of 1.5M will result in a separate page (in turn on-disk file) with a size of 1.5M.